# javascript sin validar valores

Tags: javascript, php, html, multiselect

Buen día a todos, necesito si alguien conoce me saque de una duda tengo json que me trae un respuesta en una variable, varios valores separados por comoas,

```
json[0].id_sucursal //console.log(json[0].id_sucursal) //emprime [1,2,3,4] //aca no valida los valores
```

cuando pongo esos valores de seleccion en el multiselect a travez del json[0].id_sucursal no funciona, pero si yo escribo

```
$('#sucNewUser').multiselect('select', [1, 2, 4]); //aqui si valida los valores y los selecciona

success: function (data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(json);
                $('#activa-user').val(json[0].cta_activa);
                $('#empresaUser').prop('checked', true);
                console.log('el id de sucursal es ['+json[0].id_sucursal+']'); //repuesta [1, 2, 4]
                //$('#sucNewUser').multiselect();
                $('#sucNewUser').multiselect('select', [1, 2, 4]); // Si valida
                //$('#sucNewUser').multiselect('select', json[0].id_sucursal); //No valida

                //console.log(json[0].id_sucursal);
                $('#nombreActUser').val(json[0].nombres);
                $('#apellidoActUser').val(json[0].apellidos);
                $('#userActLogin').val(json[0].nombre_usuario);
                $('#emailActUser').val(json[0].email);
                $('#permisos').val(json[0].permisos);
                $('#cargoActUser').val(json[0].id_rol_usuario);
                $('#dniActUser').val(json[0].cedula);
                $('#fechaNacActUser').val(json[0].fecha_nac);
                $('#estadoCivilActUser').val(json[0].e_civil);
                $('#emailActUserAdi').val(json[0].email_adicional);
                $('#telfActUser').val(json[0].telefono);
                $('#notasActUser').val(json[0].notas_info);
                $('#id_usuarioHidden').val(id)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay una posibilidad de que el valor de json[0].id_sucursal contenga valores tipo string ["1","2","3"].

Intenta debugearlo con console.log(typeof json[0].id_sucursal[0]) y si devuelve string tendrás que o cambiar el JSON previamente o realizar un parseInt durante

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).